# keystroke interrupt for PIC microcontroller

Tags: pic, keypad, pic18

I am writing a code where the user can press a key corresponding to the information the user wants to know and print it on the LCD Display. So far I am able to write the code to print on LCD but I am not able to figure out how to ask MCU to wait for a keystroke and then print. 
Can anyone suggest me what is the logic to do it?

Microcontroller: [PIC18F4550](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632c.pdf); MPLAB X IDE, XC8 with PICkit3. I am using Windows 7.
Keypad: 3x4 matrix keypad - [MCAK304NBWB](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1662617.pdf)

My code is:

```
#define C1_DAT LATBbits.LATB4 //Column 1 is set portB4 as output
#define C2_DAT LATBbits.LATB5 //Column 2 is set portB5 as output
#define C3_DAT LATBbits.LATB6 //Column 3 is set portB6 as output

#define C1_DIR TRISBbits.TRISB4 //Column 1 is set portB4 as output
#define C2_DIR TRISBbits.TRISB5 //Column 2 is set portB5 as output
#define C3_DIR TRISBbits.TRISB6 //Column 3 is set portB6 as output
.....

C1_DIR = 0; //drive column 1 low
        rows[0] = PORTB & 0x0f; //read all four rows1 buttons
        rows[1] = 0x0f;
        rows[2] = 0x0f;
        DelayXLCD();

        if ( (rows[0] & 0b0001) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key 1 is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();
        //break; 

        if ( (rows[0] & 0b0010) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key 4 is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();
        //break; 
        if ( (rows[0] & 0b0100) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key 7 is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();

        if ( (rows[0] & 0b1000) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key * is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();
        //break; 
        if ( (rows[1] & 0b0001) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key 2 is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();

        if ( (rows[1] & 0b0010) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key 5 is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();
        //break; 
        if ( (rows[1] & 0b0100) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key 8 is pressed");
        //break; 
        if ( (rows[1] & 0b1000) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key 0 is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();
        //break; 
        if ( (rows[2] & 0b0001) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key 3 is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();
        //break; 
        if ( (rows[2] & 0b0010) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key 6 is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();
        //break; 
        if ( (rows[2] & 0b0100) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key 9 is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();
        //break; 
        if ( (rows[2] & 0b1000) == 0)    // will be zero if the "0" button is currently pressed.
            putrsXLCD("key # is pressed");
        DelayXLCD();
        Delay_s(20);
        //if ( (rows[0] & rows[1] & rows[2]) == 0x0F)    // will be 0x0F if all three values are 0x0F
            //putrsXLCD("no keys are pressed");
        //DelayXLCD();

    } while((rows[0] & rows[1] & rows[2]) != 0x0F); // wait for keys release
    {putrsXLCD("no keys are pressed");
        Delay_s(50);
        LCD_Clear();} //end of main loop
```

Comment: Have you tried to google e.g. button interrupt?

Comment: I did. Mostly the idea I received was to STAY AWAY from interrupts if I am not an experience person, which I am not. The alternative to it was timer. I am looking into it. Just curious, how can I use timer as as interrupts? Can I use 2 timers at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Using timers in this context (regular polling of the keyboard) does not really help because they also use interrupts. You might as well dive into it and teach yourself to use interrupts. Basically, an interrupt is a SHORT piece of code that is executed when some event occurs.

For your keyboard, use an interrupt-on-change. When the interrupt triggers, read the keyboard, and set a global semaphore (flag) that your main program can check at it leisure while performing other tasks (e.g. in an event loop in the main() routine.

Alternatively, if you don't have much else to do, but continuously poll the keyboard input lines to see if there is any activity.